# git push all remote branches to a new origin

Tags: git, push, clone, mirror

Say I have a repo cloned from Remote A and now I want all Remote A branches to clone to Remote B repo. I have tried to use `git push --mirror` but it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After setting new origin:

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

I have used:

```
git push origin refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*
```

Comment: It is recommended to put the pathname in quotes due to some shells messing with the asterisks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564353/push-refs-remotes-to-new-origin-how

Comment: As @wayofthefuture noted, TCSH throws `git: No match.`. Double quote trick works:
`git push origin "refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*"`