# Push refs/remotes to new origin, how?

Tags: git

I have a repository which was pointing to an remote and now i made a new remote e.g the origin url has changed using `git remote set-url origin myNewRemote` . I then did a `git push` but since push only pushes local branches i still need to push the remote branches to the new remote. I know this is not practice but all i want to do now is tell the new remote "hey here are your remote branches you should know about" then i will go thru normal Git workflow where i create local branches/tracked and push those to the remote but right now i am in a transition to get back to what i had before moving to the new remote.

I remember doing something like this once :

`git push origin refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*` but they get created wrongly so i get origin appended to the branch names so i am pretty sure the command above (the X:Y part) is not entirely correct, can somebody help with the right one so i don't have to create all branches locally first ?

donnib

Comment: try cloning the new remote directly from the old remote.

 'cd OLD-REMOTE-DIR'   and then 'git push --mirror NEW-REMOTE-URL'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you recall:

> ```
> git push origin refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*
> ```

is very close.  Since both the old and new *`remote`* name is `origin`, the remote-tracking branches—those names under `refs/remotes/`—are specifically in the `refs/remotes/origin/` sub-name-space, and you want to discard the extra `origin/` as well.  Hence what you want is:

```
git push origin "refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/*"
```

(I added the quotes here as a protective device against the shells, which like to munch on `*` characters for breakfast. :-)  More seriously, the shell rules for globbing—characters like `*` and `?` and `[a-z]` and such—are a bit complicated, and the more sensible shells like `sh` and `bash` pass them on unchanged *if* they match no files, but this causes the occasional problem when you actually have a file named `refs/remotes/origin/foo:refs/heads/bar` for instance.)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for.